# qmake: extra compilers (processing steps)?

Tags: compiler-construction, qmake, extra, xxd

In my qmake-based project, I want to run 'xxd' on some files before compilation. Following the documentation, the relevant part in my pro file looks as following:

```
SHADERS = shader/tone.frag \
          shader/trans.frag \
          shader/hue.frag

# xxd
xxd.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}.xxd
xxd.commands = xxd -i ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} > ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
xxd.depends = SHADERS
xxd.input = $$SHADERS
xxd.variable_out = HEADERS

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += xxd
```

Qmake doesn't complain, but it also doesn't run xxd at all. Do I have to create special targets for each file I want to have pre-processed? (The resulting *.xxd files will **not** be compiled afterwards by me, only included in other cpp files)

**Edit:** With smokris's help, this is how I fixed the part in my pro file:

```
# xxd
xxd.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}.xxd
xxd.commands = xxd -i ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} > ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
xxd.depends = $$SHADERS
xxd.input = SHADERS
xxd.variable_out = HEADERS
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I just figured out my confusion about `.variable_out` and clarified my answer.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is looking at this and can't make it work: I had to add `$${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}.xxd` (it was called differently in my code) to the .depends list. So for me it was `xxd.depends = SHADERS $${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}.xxd`. Without it the shader compiler didn't execute in case of a re-build and `$${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}.xxd` was never created.

Comment: I made all the above changes, and nothing happened. It turns out you need to actually #include the generated file into your C++ file, and then run qmake. Then the dependencies will be updated and it will generate the file. Or you can alternatively do "xxd.CONFIG = target_predeps" to force it to generate the file even if not used anywhere. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.input` attribute expects the name of a variable, not a list of files.  Try taking away the `$$` and just use `xxd.input = SHADERS`.

`.depends`, on the other hand, expects a list of files, so use `xxd.depends = $$SHADERS`.

If you set `.variable_out` to `HEADERS`, `SOURCES`, or `OBJECTS`, the compiler will run.  However, if you set `.variable_out` to another variable name, you must also set `.CONFIG = target_predeps` in order for the compiler to run.